# VBScript howto split a quoted delimited AND spaced separate values?

Tags: vbscript, split

I have the following string:

"C:\Program Files\Application\Path\executable.exe" -- "/flag"

I am trying to split the string so that I get:

array(0) = C:\Program Files\Application\Path\executable.exe

I don't care about the rest of the array since I am just concerned about the file path not the args.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.

```
dim p : p = """C:\Program Files\Application\Path\executable.exe"" -- ""/flag"
dim r : r = mid(p,2,instr(2,p,"""")-2)
```

Comment: You could also use `Left(p, InStr(p, """")-1)`.

Comment: @Helen, I chose mid because I had intended to jump the first quotation mark.  My answer however did not take it into account, I've corrected it.

Comment: both worked great! Thanks for the help. I was stuck in this for hours

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with `Mid` and `InStr`, you can make use of regular expressions. For example, this will retrieve the first quoted substring (without the outer quotes) from your string:

```
Dim strCommandLine, strPath, re

strCommandLine = """C:\Program Files\Application\Path\executable.exe"" -- ""/flag"""

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = """(.*?)"""

strPath = re.Execute(strCommandLine)(0).SubMatches(0)
```

Comment: both worked great! Thanks for the help. I was stuck in this for hours